# Many IF statements vs Delegates?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, delegates, xna

Would it be better for performance to use if statements over and over again, or to use them once and use delegates to call functions based on the output from the IF statements? I want to say that the answer is obviously delegates, but I'm not sure if going to different methods over and over is faster or slower than many IF statements that do the same thing. I hope I explained it right.

PS The framework I need to know this for is XNA, if it matters.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on more information than you can really give us here.  You should write both, profile both, and compare the results.  That will give you a much more definitive answer.

Comment: There are many unclear things here; are your delegates using closures or are they assigned only once early in the rpocess? Would it be possible to leverage virtual methods instead? Did you think about using a dictionary with delegates?

Comment: It sounds like a state machine you are describing, is it one?

Comment: The delegates are going to be assigned early on, but may change later on. Forgive my ignorance, but what is a "dictionary with delegates"?

Comment: @leaf68: Google "state machine" and then answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your trade offs. The best answer was commented already and that is to profile both and then figure it out. IF statements may take more CPU because it has to do the comparisons again and again. On the other hand using delegates takes more memory and it's another object you need to keep around.

Personally what I've like doing the best (when applicable, don't know the full context of your question) is turning your IF ELSE statements into a switch-case. This works really well for state machines and other repetitive processes plus you eliminate all that branching that comes with IFs. However, this is assuming that the values your are checking for are all relatively close in range or else you'll be causing a lot of pain for the compiler.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice, +1 for the trade-off between memory and performance, forgot about memory...

Answer (score 1):

That is a useful technique, sure. Clearly, for only a few if's delegates don't make sense because they are costly and the CPU cannot easily predict the branch target. And for very many if's a one-time initialized delegate makes sense.

It is unclear where the break-even point is. That one needs to be measured.

Comment: +1 for noting that it needs to be measured, but leaf68 wants to bind the delegate once, so I think if anything branch prediction is just a mitigating factor for the "if" camp.

Comment: I wanted to say that if's *can* be predicted and delegates not.